# ERROR al instalar el paquete de eeconvert para python 3

Tags: python-3.x, windows10

Estoy tratando de instalar el paquete eeconvert para python 3 usando el comando:

```
pip install eeconvert
```

Sistema operativo:win 10
Empieza ha instalar pero no lograr terminar la instalación sale el error:

```
ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\arles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3ld09g0j\shapely\setup.py", line 80, in <module>
    from shapely._buildcfg import geos_version_string, geos_version, \
  File "C:\Users\arles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3ld09g0j\shapely\shapely\_buildcfg.py", line 200, in <module>
    lgeos = CDLL("geos_c.dll")
  File "c:\python37-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\arles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3ld09g0j\shapely\
```

Alguien sabe la manera correcta de realizar la instalación del paquete?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Windows es un dolor de cabeza con módulos que requieren compilar código c/c++ previamente. En eeconvert especifica que [debes tener instalado un compilador (Microsoft Visual)](https://github.com/rutgerhofste/eeconvert#installation).

Comment: El problema concreto que muestras lo da al instalar `shapely`, una de las dependencias, a causa de una de las librerías de enlace dinámico en lenguaje C. Puedes descargar el binario precompilado desde https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely y luego instalarlo con PIP. En tu caso descarga `Shapely‑1.6.4.post1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl` (dado que usas Python 32 bits) y luego en CMD posicionada en la carpeta de descarga debes hacer `pip install Shapely‑1.6.4.post1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl` o bien desde cualquier lado con `pip install ruta/absoluta/archivo.whl`

Comment: gracias Se instalo correctamente el shapely, sin embargo ahora me sale un error distinto.

Comment: ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\arles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-62_x5wvz\fiona\

Comment: Descargue de aqui https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona, fiona y lo instale con:pip install Fiona-1.8.6-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl y luego ejecute pip install eeconvert y todo fue bien, gracias @FJSevilla me diste una buena pista para soucionar mi problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les dejo un vídeo donde se explica como instalar eeconvert: https://youtu.be/2F4cUfkP4fU

- Requisitos: tener instalado MicroSoft Visual
- Versión de python: 3.7
- Comprobar que versión de python que tienes instalado si la de 32-bit o 64-bit.
- Descargar paquetes necesarios para la instalación dependiendo de la versión que tengas  desde: 
   https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
- Paquetes a instalar shapely, fiona y GDAL.
- Instalando usando el comando pip install [[tu ruta]]/paquete.whl o te mueves a la ruta 
  donde tienes el paquete y ejecutas: pip install paquete.whl
- Finalmente ejecutas pip install eeconvert y listo ya tendras instalado eeconvert.